# Mongodb calculation query--cummulative multiplication

Tags: mongodb, calculation

I recently started working in Mongodb for POC. I have one json collection below

```
db.ccpsample.insertMany([
  {
    "ccp_id":1,
    "period":601,
    "sales":100.00
  },
  {
    "ccp_id":1,
    "period":602,
    "growth":2.0,
    "sales":"NULL"    ##sales=100.00*(1+(2.0/100)) -- 100.00 comes from(ccp_id:1 and period=601) 
  },
  {
    "ccp_id":1,
    "period":603,
    "growth":3.0,
    "sales":"NULL"   ##sales=100.00*(1+(2.0/100))**(1+(3.0/100))-- 100.00 comes from(ccp_id:1 and period=601) 2.0 comes from (ccp_id:2 and period=602)  
  },
  {
    "ccp_id":2,
    "period":601,
    "sales":200.00
  },
  {
    "ccp_id":2,
    "period":602,
    "growth":2.0,
    "sales":"NULL"   ##sales=200.00*(1+(2.0/100))
  },
  {
    "ccp_id":2,
    "period":603,
    "growth":3.0,
    "sales":"NULL"   ##same like above
  }
])
```

And i need to calculate sales field which has NULL by using above documents with matching conditions of ccp_id should same and period field should be equal to 601. I have added a line to demonstrate calculation of sales field in collection itself above. I tried with $graphlookup but no luck. Can you people kindly help or suggest some way?

Comment: Can you provide the formula of the `sales`? Because those examples do not help much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.ccpsample.aggregate([
  { $sort: { ccp_id: 1, period: 1 } },
  { 
    $group: {
      _id: "$ccp_id",
      items: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
      baseSale: { $first: "$sales" },
      growths: { $push: "$growth" }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$items",
      includeArrayIndex: "index"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      cpp_id: "$items.cpp_id",
      period: "$items.period",
      growth: "$items.growth",
      sales: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $ne: [ "$items.sales", "NULL" ] },
          then: "$items.sales",
          else: {
            $reduce: {
              input: { $slice: [ "$growths", "$index" ] },
              initialValue: "$baseSale",
              in: { $multiply: [ "$$value", { $add: [1, { $divide: [ "$$this", 100 ] }] } ] }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Basically to calculate the value for `n-th` element you have to know following things:

- sales value of first element (`$first` in `$group`)
- the array of all `growths` (`$push` in `$group`)
- the `n` which indicates how many multiplications you have to perform

To calculate the index you should `$push` all elements into one array and then use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) with `includeArrayIndex` option which will insert the index of unwinded array to field `index`.

Last step calculates the cumulative multiplication. It uses [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/index.html) with `index` field to evaluate how many `growths` should be processed. So there will be one element for `601`, two elements for `602` and so on.

Then it's time for [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to process that array and perform the multiplications based on your formula: (`1 + (growth/100)`)

Comment: Change `$slice` spec to `$slice: [ "$growths", 1, "$index" ]` to offset the slicing properly. Otherwise nice solution!

Comment: @DonnyWinston I can't do it. `growths` is a 2 element array in both groups since there is no `growth` for first document in each group so no need to have an offset

Comment: @mickl Thanks for the answer !! And can you give any suggestions to me get strengthen in mongodb aggregation?

Comment: @Buddi I believe that writing code is the best way to learn programming :) In this case MongoDB has really useful docs. Thanks for really interesting question !

Comment: @mickl thanks, you're right! I thought a null value would be `$push`ed for a document with no "growth" field, but you're right, it's a 2-element array. Thanks for clarifying!