# MongoDB Charts – chart cumulative growth?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-charts

Using [MongoDB Charts](https://www.mongodb.com/products/charts), how can I chart cumulative growth? Using the `_id` value of a document which contains the information of when it was created, I'd like to chart the number of documents in my database over time. E.g., if in July 10 documents were created, and in August another 10 were created, then the chart should display 10 for July and 20 for August.

It's easy to bin document creation dates per months (see below example), but I'd like to turn this into a cumulative growth chart. MongoDB Charts can use Mongo aggregation pipelines, if that helps…

[image: chart demonstrating binned dates]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've already answered similar question some time ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49606178/6238977) however it would be good to walk you through entire solution.

Yes, you need an aggregation to reshape your data. To get started you need to convert your ObjectId values into Dates using [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/index.html) operator. Using [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html) will allow you to categorize these dates by day. Then you can [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) them and count.

To calculate the "cummulative" part you need to get them all into single document (grouping by `null`), This will allow you to run [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) on [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html) of numbers that will be representing array indexes (`0,1,2` etc). For each index you take corresponding date to the output and [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/index.html) [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/index.html) -ed array of values.

The rest is easy as you just need to run [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get single document per day and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to get rid of nested document in your final result.

```
[
    { $addFields: { "date": { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: { $toDate: "$_id" }} } }},
    { $group: { _id: "$date", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
    { $group: { _id: null, days: { $push: "$_id" }, counts: { $push: "$count" } } },
    { $project: { 
        days: { 
            $map: { 
                input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$days" } ] }, 
                in: { _id: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$days", "$$this" ] }, cumGrowth: { $sum: { $slice: [ "$counts", 0, { $add: [ "$$this", 1 ] } ] } } }
                } 
            } 
        } 
    },
    { $unwind: "$days" },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$days" } },
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
]
```

Using Mongo Charts you just need to map output fields into X and Y axis

[image]