# MongoDB Charts – chart cumulative growth with multiple group attributes?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to extend the answer provided in [MongoDB Charts – chart cumulative growth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412129/mongodb-charts-chart-cumulative-growth#new-answer?newreg=42c7432debd545b88d847c2da51e1072) to group by multiple attributes.

Basically if the data has a date and a type A, B and C. I want to get the cumulative totals of All the A's,the cumulative totals of All the B's and the cumulative totals of All the C's.
I know I could do this in seperate graphs but it would be nice to create one pipeline with more dimensions of attributes.
The first few parts of the pipeline I can see what to do but I need help with the map section to total up the records per type and not everything upto that date.
Here is the code so far....

```
[                                                                               
  { $addFields: { "date": { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: { $toDate: "$_id" }} } 
  ,             "document_type": "$document_type" }},                           
    { $group: { _id: {"date":"$date", "document_type": "$document_type"}, count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } },                                                      
    { $group: { _id: null, days: { $push: "$_id" }, counts: { $push: "$count" } } },
    { $project: {                                                               
        days: {                                                                 
            $map: {                                                             
                input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$days" } ] },                   
                in: { _id: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$days", "$$this" ] }, cumGrowth: { $sum: { $slice: [ "$counts", 0, { $add: [ "$$this", 1 ] } ] } } } 
                }                                                               
            }                                                                   
        }                                                                       
    },                                                                          
    { $unwind: "$days" },                                                       
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$days" } },                                     
    { $sort: { _id: 1 } },                                                      
]
```

Can anyone please help calculate the correct cumulative totals in the map section?

Current code for  this data:

```
Date 1-1-20, document_type = A 
Date 1-1-20, document_type = B 
Date 1-1-20, document_type = C 
Date 1-1-20, document_type = A 
Date 2-1-20, document_type = A 
Date 2-1-20, document_type = B 
Date 2-1-20, document_type = B
```

gives

```
date 1-1-20 type A count 2
date 1-1-20 type B count 1
date 1-1-20 type C count 1
date 2-1-20 type A count **5** <-- should be 3 but includes the B's and C's from 1-1-20
date 2-1-20 type B count **6**
Date 2-1-20, type C count **4**
```

Comment: please share json data

Comment: The json is a very simple list of document types which I would like to group by dates.e.g.
{{    "_id_date":'1-1-20',    "document_type':'A'  },
{    "_id_date"': '1-1-20', 'document_type':'B'  },
{    "_id_date": '1-1-20', 'document_type': 'C'  },
{    "_id_date": '1-1-20', 'document_type': 'A'  },
{    "_id_date": '2-1-20', 'document_type': 'A'  },
{    "_id_date": '2-1-20', 'document_type': 'B'  },
 {    "_id_date": "2-1-20", 'document_type': 'B'  } }